# Overriding destructors without calling their parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

I'm writing a class that inherits from some library.

In said class I'm overriding the destructor so that I can call some function that does cleaning in a certain way. If I don't call *super().__del__()* does that still mean that resources are cleaned at the destruction of the class? Is there a chance that this piece of code for example introduces a memory leak?

```
class foo(some_library):
    ...

    def __del__(self):
        self.proprietary_cleaning_function()
```

Are functions like *__init__* or *__del__* different in the way they are overriden and does the garbage collection mechanism in python work after *__del__*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to explicitly call the base classes destructor to ensure that python will delete the object entirely.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> If a base class has a `__del__()` method, the derived class’s `__del__()`
>   method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of
>   the base class part of the instance.

Also note that since `__del__()` method is only called when your object  reference count reaches zero, there are Some common situations that may prevent the reference count of an object from going to zero include:

> circular references between objects (e.g., a doubly-linked list or a
>   tree data structure with parent and child pointers); a reference to
>   the object on the stack frame of a function that caught an exception
>   (the traceback stored in `sys.exc_info()` keeps the stack frame
>   alive); or a reference to the object on the stack frame that raised an
>   unhandled exception in interactive mode (the traceback stored in
>   `sys.last_traceback` keeps the stack frame alive).
>
> The first situation can only be remedied by explicitly breaking the
>   cycles; the second can be resolved by freeing the reference to the
>   traceback object when it is no longer useful, and the third can be
>   resolved by storing None in sys.last_traceback. Circular references
>   which are garbage are detected and cleaned up when the cyclic garbage
>   collector is enabled (it’s on by default). Refer to the documentation
>   for the gc module for more information about this topic.

Comment: Is that the same case for when the \_\_del\_\_ method is not implemented in the parent class? i.e overriding objects del?

Comment: @GLaDOS No, when the parent class doesn't have the `__del__` method. But if it has the method built-in you still need to call it explicitly.